# Conditional Stack Allocation

Tags: c

I have a method that takes a pointer T to a valid memory block. Is the following wise within that method given that no stack overflow will result since the constant some_defined constant is known to be small?

```
if (T)
{
    p = T;
    q = T + k;
}
else
{
    unsigned long long TT[2 * some_defined constant];
    p = TT;
    q = TT + k;
}

<code using p and q>
```

I would never contemplate doing this except that I know the method is being called concurrently; it is called five times, each call being on a separate thread. The method that makes such a call uses an OMP loop. If that calling method invoking the OMP loop is to cater for the required extra memory required and pre-allocated in T it needs to request from the caller an allocation of 10 * some_defined constant words, if the method called within the OMP loop allocates 2 * some_defined constant then that would work very well. It would be great to make this conditional so as that when the risk of a stack overflow appears to be possible the call to the top method can be made after allocating 10 * some_defined constant words on the heap.

Comment: Apologies, I made a typo and corrected.

Comment: No, given that 2 * sdc will not overlow I want to allocate on the stack.

Comment: He wants to know if its defined behavior to access TT indirectly outside of its declared scope, and the answer is **no**.

Comment: The information regarding the variable length array is appreciated, apologies for phrasing the question badly.

Comment: The following does not compile with Visual Studio 2012. I assume I must wait for the new C99 standard? unsigned long long TT[T == 0 ? 50 : 1];

Comment: Each thread has its own stack, so the number of threads calling it should be irrelevant?

Comment: You say you're sure overflow is not possible, but just to be on the safe side: `(2*some_value)%max_size_plus_one` modulo might be safer still... you never know if the const value changes somewhere down the line

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem But if you then allocate too few bytes, you are bitten as well. Maybe better use `malloc()` then?

Comment: @glglgl: Of course... but given the code posted here, I think the hole approach to whatever the OP is trying to do should be changed. This just doesn't sit well with me

Answer (score 7):

The lifetime of the `TT` array only extends until leaving the block in which it was declared (the `else` block). So your code will result in undefined behavior when it is accessed past the end of the `else` block.

If you move the declaration of `TT` to above the `if` statement, the code will be correct. But of course it will be allocated on the stack even when it isn't needed.

As noted in a comment by user self, You can change the size of `TT` based on whether it is needed by using C99 variable length arrays:

```
unsigned long long TT[is_needed ? some_size : 1];
```

Comment: You could make a variable length array, and make it the minimal size if not needed.

Answer (score 3):

In this case I would do (pseudo-code):

```
void function_which_does_the_job(... p, ... q)
{
    <code using p and q>
}

if (T)
{
    function_which_does_the_job(T, T+k);
}
else
{
    unsigned long long TT[2 * some_defined constant];
    function_which_does_the_job(TT, TT+k);
}
```

Then you don't repeat yourself and nevertheless can do what you want.

If your compiler indeed doesn't support VLAs, do

```
if (T)
{
    function_which_does_the_job(T, T+k);
}
else
{
    unsigned long long * TT = malloc(2 * some_defined constant * sizeof(*TT));
    function_which_does_the_job(TT, TT+k);
    free(TT);
}
```

instead.

(Of course, you'll have to pass other variables down to the function as well; if `k` is amongst these, you can omit `q` and determine it in the function.)

Comment: Also better from a 'single responsibility' point of view, putting memory allocation and business logic into separate functions; +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `alloca` function for dynamically allocating bytes on the stack. Like the C99 variable length arrays, it provides no means to detect allocation failure, so it bears a certain risk unless you ensure that the allocated amount is small.

```
if(T) {
    p = T;
    q = T + k;
} else {
    p = alloca(2 * some_defined constant * sizeof(long long));
    q = p + k;
}
/* use p and q until the end of the function scope */
```